# accelerating solutions of ODEs with close by parameters

Tags: ode, newton-method, acceleration

Suppose $\mathbf{u}^1\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an unknown and $\mu^1\in\mathbb{R}$ is a known parameter. Suppose we have solved the non-linear system of equation for $\mathbf{u}^1$ using Newton's iterations.

$$
\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{u}^1;\mu^1)=0
$$

Using $\mathbf{u}^1$ as an initial guess for the Newton iterations, it is possible to accelerate the solution of the system

$$
\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{u}^2;\mu^2) = 0 
$$

where $\mu^1$ and $\mu^2$ are sufficiently close. Now, is it possible to extend this to ODEs? For instance, if I have solved

$$
\frac{d\mathbf{u}^1}{dt} = \mathcal{M}(\mathbf{u}^1;\mu^1)
$$

Is it possible to accelerate the solution of

$$
\frac{d\mathbf{u}^2}{dt} = \mathcal{M}(\mathbf{u}^2;\mu^2)
$$

where $\mu^1$ and $\mu^2$ again are sufficiently close.

The only thing I can think of is to integrate both ODEs implicitly with the same time-step. Solve the first ODE, and use the solution at each time-step to accelerate Newton's iterations for the second. Can anything else be done?

Comment: The start point for the Newton iteration is usually derived from the previous time step. I don't expect a major boost from using the start points from the "neighbouring" solution.
I would see a chance to use a close by solution in iterative methods (e.g., multigrid in time, [ParaReal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parareal), multiple shooting).

Comment: If the parameters really only change a small amount, then the solution is a linear function of the parameters and you can solve it for a small additional cost by computing the *sensitivity* of $u^1$  with regards to the parameters, and then computing $u^2$ as $u^1 + s(\mu^2-\mu_1)$ where $s$ is the computed sensitivity.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth In general the sensitivity will depend on $t$. Consider for example $d_t u = \mu u$.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Right. But the formula I stated is still true if you put a time dependence on $u$ and $s$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Yes, your formula is still true, but the utility of it is not so clear. If you have to find the sensitivity for each point in time, how is this going to save the overall computational effort? Calculating the sensitivity would cost more than solving the equation directly, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @MaximUmansky No, you misunderstand: $s(t)$ satisfies an ODE that can be solved alongside the original ODE. ODE solver packages often offer this functionality -- for example, the SUNDIALS package has IDA to solve ODEs and IDAS to solve the sensitivity equations alongside.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Yes, solving the sensitivity equation alongside the original ODE is a great idea, this seems to be the right way to solve this problem, at least in the limit of a small increment of the parameter $\mu$. You should write this up as an answer.